# Is There a Way to Create Invisible Floating Armorstands That Can Move(Spigot API)?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

Is there anyway to create an armorstand that is invisible to players and can float in air? I'm trying to make something like a boomerang that can be thrown but that requires an armorstand to show the boomerang itself. For example: [Video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATv8K.jpg). I use spigot-api-1.16.5-R0.1-20210220.225230-24 as my api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You need to spawn in a armor stand, then disable the gravity for it using `armorstand.setGravity(false)`, store it in a array, and then create a loop that runs every tick, and teleports it to the desired location.